# paperclip gem load error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I tried to run rails/generate paperclip photo data and the following error occured:

```
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/rubygems_integrat
ion.rb:143:in `block in replace_gem': paperclip is not part of the bundle. Add i
t to Gemfile. (Gem::LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby192/rubydev/upload/config/environment.rb:6:in `<top (require
d)>'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.0.rc2/lib/rails/ap
plication.rb:103:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.0.rc2/lib/rails/ap
plication.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.0.rc2/lib/rails/co
mmands.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I am trying to upload and store an image using ruby on rails.

Comment: Do you have `gem paperclip` line written in **`Gemfile`** of your app??

Comment: in migration files i written it.

Comment: write `gem paperclip` in your **Gemfile** and then `bundle install`

Comment: i want paperclip gem to be placed in my Gemfile.lock

Comment: delete **Gemfile.lock** and then `bundle update`!!

Comment: surya am trying it kindly wait it seems to be worth :)

Comment: surya the following occurs i did exactly what u said:      Installing paperclip (2.5.0)
Errno::EINVAL: Invalid argument - C:/Ruby192/rubydev/upload/paperclip/ruby/1.9.1
/gems/paperclip-2.5.0/test/fixtures/question?mark.png
An error occured while installing paperclip (2.5.0), and Bundler cannot continue
.
Make sure that `gem install paperclip -v '2.5.0'` succeeds before bundling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write `gem paperclip, '2.5.0'` in your **Gemfile**. Delete **Gemfile.lock** and then `bundle install` or `bundle update`

Comment: surya the following occurs i did exactly what u said: Installing paperclip (2.5.0) Errno::EINVAL: Invalid argument - C:/Ruby192/rubydev/upload/paperclip/ruby/1.9.1 /gems/paperclip-2.5.0/test/fixtures/question?mark.png An error occured while installing paperclip (2.5.0), and Bundler cannot continue . Make sure that gem install paperclip -v '2.5.0' succeeds before bundling.

Comment: write `gem paperclip, '2.5.0` and then try the same again!!

Answer (score 1):

From within your application directory, run the following from the command line,

bundle install paperclip

Comment: i did what u said the following occured at the end is there any problem Your bundle is complete! It was installed into ./paperclip
The path argument to `bundle install` is deprecated. It will be removed in versi
on 1.1. Please use `bundle install --path paperclip` instead.